# JqueryUI Datepicker: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am developing a asp.net MVC4 project where i use lots of JqueryUI datepicker.

For one of my date picker when i tried to click on datepicker image i am getting some error like,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined                jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js:9
```

Html

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="tsDte"  style="font-size: 14px;width: 50%" >              
                <img src="~/Images/dayPicker.png" onclick="tsDatePickerClick()" style="vertical-align:bottom"/>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var currentDate = new Date();

$("#tsDte").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: 0,
    changeYear: true 
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
$("#tsDte").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);


function tsDatePickerClick() {
    $("#tsDte").datepicker('show');
}
```

Here i have a Textfield and a datepicker image.When i click on datepicker image datepicker will popup .

i have followed the similar way in other datepicker and they are working fine.I have only problem with this date picker.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CEPth/1/

Comment: assuming you have used dom ready handler

Comment: without dom ready handler it fails http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CEPth/3/

Comment: is it necessary to add $(document).ready(function() in all javascript files.Mine is a single page web application.

Comment: In my case it was incompatibility between jquery and jquery ui libraries. jquery was 1.9.* and jquery ui was 1.10.*. After updating jquery to 1.10.*, the issue was solved

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your datepicker wasn't created correctly, so when you call `show`, it expects a `settings` object.

Probably you didn't create it inside `$(document).ready`, you should have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      //Add this line (and it's closing line)
    var currentDate = new Date();

    $("#tsDte").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        maxDate: 0,
        changeYear: true 
    }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    $("#tsDte").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thans for the reply.Is it necessary to add $(document).ready(function() in all javascript files.Mine is a single page web application.

Comment: You have to add it practically everywhere you create a `datepicker`

Comment: :D Just a note, you have to add document ready only if you're creating datepicker at the beginning (when the page loads)

Answer (score 36):

That same error will be shown if you try to open a datepicker on an input field who has the class "hasDatepicker" assigned. Simply remove this class in the html.

Before:

```
<input type="text" value="01/01/2014" class="hasDatepicker">
```

After:

```
<input type="text" value="01/01/2014">
```

Comment: Mine too :) had datepicker didn't show when wired through the Angular directive, removing that class somehow fixed it.

Comment: I cannot believe this was my issue. Spent over 3 hrs! Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

You are including the `jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js` library.

Your issue is caused by duplicating your jQuery UI core scripts.(check if you are including any other librady such as `jquery-ui-1.10.3.drag-drop.min.js` .

Load just them once, and your issue will go away.

Comment: In this vein, check your AppStart/BundleConfig.cs. Comment everything out and add the jquery to the front-end to test. This is what did it for me; there were obviously bundled librar(ies) interfering with the javascript loading.

Answer (score 1):

On refreshing the page, you need to remove class 'hasDatepicker' and then set the settings (again). On refresh, the class is kept and so the datepicker is not recreated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused because I had an span with id `date` and the input had the same id. Giving the input a different id solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue because I had both 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "DatePicker" })
and 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StartDate)

in the same form on my view.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is probably the solution for most people, but This can happen when the picker is properly initialized but another element higher up in the DOM has the same id as your date input element.

You can check if that's the case by querying for this in your browser's console: `$('*[id=my-id]');`

The code for this datepicker is fairly old and therefore doesn't follow the best practices - it relies on the id attribute when it should really have just tracked the original DOM element reference, but it is what it is.