# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using Jquery UI datepicker for my angular application.

Getting following error when open datepicker

```
Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
at n._get (jquery-ui.min.js?v=11.0.0.0_RC2:2028)
at n._showDatepicker (jquery-ui.min.js?v=11.0.0.0_RC2:1736)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js?v=11.0.0.0_RC2:2255)
at Function.each (jquery-3.0.0.js?v=11.0.0.0_RC2:359)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.0.0.js?v=11.0.0.0_RC2:152)
at jQuery.fn.init.e.fn.datepicker (jquery-ui.min.js?v=11.0.0.0_RC2:2254)
```

This is my HTML code

```
<div #btn class="hold_img_only icon_space clickable" (click)="onShowCalendar()">
```

This is my ts code

```
onShowCalendar() {
   $(this.btn.nativeElement).datepicker("show");
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: // Reference btn variable inside Component
@ViewChild('btn') btnRef: ElementRef;

Comment: @SaurabhYadav i have already added the reference, still getting same error

Comment: Try using event.currentTarget in your click function by passing event obj like this (click)="onShowCalendar($event)".

Comment: @Prawinsoni how to use event.currentTarget in my click function??. Sorry I'm not that much familiar with jquery

Comment: So your function will be onShowCalendar(event) {
   $(event.currentTarget).datepicker("show");
}

Comment: @Prawinsoni unfortunately that's also not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987889/jqueryui-datepicker-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-settings-of-unde . Also you should not use jQuery into an Angular project.